# sql = "INSERT INTO daftar_film (`judul_film`) VALUES (%s)"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, mariadb

Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%s)' at line 1
>   my code

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="db_bioskop")

    if db.is_connected():
        print("Berhasil terhubung ke database")
    else:
        print("eror")

    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO daftar_film (`judul_film`) VALUES (%s)"
    val = (str(var_films2.get()))
    cursor.execute(sql, val)

    db.commit()
    print("{} data ditambahkan")
```

Comment: Can you share your Python code?

Comment: you are replacing %s with something ?

Comment: Adhy Please add respective sql script and python code.

Comment: `%s` should be `?`, and you should be providing the argument value somewhere.

Comment: I already have an argument

Comment: So you're halfway there. All you need now is to use the correct syntax for it.

Comment: @user207421 whats the correct syntax?

Comment: I've already told you that.

Comment: consider using array such as `val = [ ( str(var_films2.get()) ) ]`

Comment: how it's a ? now, thought it was %s

Comment: @user207421 No, the `%s` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you need are:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO daftar_film (`judul_film`) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (val,))
```

Each parameter in your prepared statement is represented by `%s` and the actual values are passed in the call to `execute` as either a `tuple` or `list` as the second parameter. Note that in the above call the actual tuple is specified as `(val,)`. That comma is important; without the comma it would just be considered a parenthesized expression.